# What was the first film project to have double directors?

Tags: first-appearance, film-industry, directors

I was recently watching the latest season of *Star Trek: Discovery*. While watching the opening credits, I noticed that two episodes of [season 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery_(season_4)) had two directors listed for those two episodes: Christopher J Bryne & Jen McGowan (4.08), and Jeff Byrd & (again) Jen Mcgowan (4.11).

Now I have seen pairs of screen writers (such as Alexander Kurtzman and former writing partner Roberto Orci) and I know that there are assistant directors, special scene choreographers, and/or cinematographers/art of Photography that can be additional to any given director, but I don't recall seeing a double director feature film or TV series episode before.

What was the first film project to do this, and what is the general/common purpose if it?

Comment: Many many. The Farrelly Bros, the Coens, the Warshowskis etc etc. It's usually the DGA that requires one director for "record/award" purposes.

Comment: As I mentioned there's no rule against it except for Award purposes I think.

Comment: idk these episodes, but it's often done in TV shows when they have a flashback to another episode. The current & previous directors are both credited. Also if it's a double-episode story & the blocks as shot have been re-edited so parts of both end up in a single episode.

Comment: The first ever projected film: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000012/

Comment: @Paulie_D ah,yes I did totally forget about those two examples! But they are pretty contemporary...wonder if there is anything earlier??

Comment: @Tetsujin Cool! Both of these don't have flashbacks to earlier episodes, but interestingly both have one of the same directors...

Comment: @magarnicle WOW! That's old!!! If you would make an answer with another source (imdb isn't always reliable, even though I suspect it's accurate) and I would be happy to 1+

Comment: Are you asking specifically about multiple directors directing the _same_ scenes? Or would you also include movies containing some scenes from one director and other scenes from another? (For an example of the latter, the 1967 [_Casino Royale_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061452/) had 5 or 6 separate directors…)

Comment: @gidds I'm just looking for "first appearence" films or TV episodes that credit double directors.

Comment: @DarthLocke Wikipedia only lists Louis as the director. I'll see what I can find from an better source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first film ever projected - [L'Arrivee d'un Train a La Ciotat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjtXXypztyw) (1895) - is [sometimes credited](http://www.film-documentaire.fr/4DACTION/w_fiche_film/22253) as being directed by both Louis and Auguest Lumière. [Other sources](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Truffaut_on_Cinema/8cSCDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=director+of+%22L%27arriv%C3%A9e+d%27un+train+%C3%A0+La+Ciotat%22&pg=PA48&printsec=frontcover), however, only list Louis. As far as I can tell the film itself does not have any credits, and this was obviously before any bodies such as film guilds that could act as an official source.